# Strange error running casperjs fom PHP exec

Tags: php, terminal, web-scraping, centos, casperjs

Here's my PHP code (test.php):

```
<?php
echo "Running PhantomJS version: ";
echo exec('phantomjs --version 2>&1');
echo "<br />";
echo "Running CasperJS version: ";
echo exec('casperjs --version 2>&1');
```

I can run this without any problem directly from terminal:

```
# php /home/username/public_html/website/test.php
```

This returns:

> Running PhantomJS version: 2.1.1
> Running CasperJS version: 1.1.2

But when running from the browser (www.website.com/test.php), it returns:

> Running PhantomJS version: 2.1.1 
> Running CasperJS version: string(64)
>   " and file a bug report."

**PS:**  
Server: CentOS 6.7
Both files are on /usr/local/bin

Also when I execute this on terminal:

```
ls -l casperjs phantomjs
```

I get all correctly:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4061 Jul 12 11:25 casperjs*
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67932064 Jul 10 06:47 phantomjs*

Any help is very appreciated!

**EDIT**

When running with shell_exec I get another strange error from browser (from terminal is ok again):

> Running PhantomJS version: 2.1.1  Running CasperJS version: 1
>   0x1b67967 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x1b67967] 2 0x1baaaf5
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x1baaaf5] 3 0x198c463
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x198c463] 4 0x1ab3982
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x1ab3982] 5 0x79abb9
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x79abb9] 6 0x76b6f9
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x76b6f9] 7 0x750a5d
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x750a5d] 8 0x41cd89
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x41cd89] 9 0x41f5c4
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x41f5c4] 10 0x415b86
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x415b86] 11 0x7f27f9ee0d1d
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f27f9ee0d1d] 12 0x4176a1
>   /usr/local/bin/phantomjs() [0x4176a1] PhantomJS has crashed. Please
>   read the bug reporting guide at and file a bug report.